# Accessing postgresql's timestamp field from Oracle via ODBC cause a loss of time precision in microsecond

Tags: oracle, postgresql, timestamp, odbc, dblink

I am trying to access PostgreSQL record from Oracle via ODBC, there is a severe problem when I try to read timestamp field, the precision of time in microsecond has been lost. For example: **2018-01-25 12:40:20.123456** in PostgreSQL will be **2018-01-25 12:40:20.000000** in the Oracle. To make sure, I have write PL/SQL to check the data, somehow all microsecond digits has been lost.

There's a documentation talking about connection string's parameter **BTD** - **BIND TIMESTAMP AS DATE** [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183)

By default, this parameter should be "FALSE"

> Bind TIMESTAMP as DATE (BTD Connect String)
>
> Added the new connection option, Bind TIMESTAMP as DATE, that allows you to bind the ODBC driver SQL_TIMESTAMP data type to the Oracle DATE data type instead of to the Oracle TIMESTAMP data type (which is the default).

Here is my PL/SQL:

```
declare
  v_timestamp timestamp(6);
begin
  select max("MODIFIED_ON") into v_timestamp from "public"."DAS_ITEM"@PG_LINK;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_timestamp);
end;
```

The result is: **19/JAN/18 08:59:42.000000 AM** , it's missing microsecond, all 6-digit second fraction has been replace to zero.

On the other hand, on my PostgreSQL, the result is "2018-01-19 08:59:42.695166"

I also have tested with `isql`, it return timestamp value with whole precision, as a consequence, I believe that the main reason comes from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle DATE datatype does not support fractions of seconds. You need to use TIMESTAMP for that. This also applies to any table columns or PL/SQL datatypes PostgreSQL timestamps go into; if the timestamps are passed into a DATE somewhere, fractions of seconds will be truncated.

Comment: in the PL/SQL, I declared a variable with timestamp(6) data type, I then fetch the max value of timestamp from PostgreSQL, inserted into that variable. When I do print value, it missed the microsecond. By default, I should get full precision timestamp. Something happen in the middle. Did you try to fetch timestamp from PostgreSQL, how was that going?

Comment: How do you print? Also, try NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT  = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'

Comment: I have tried to `alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF';` then run my PL/SQL again. The result is: `2018-01-19 08:59:42.000000`

Comment: A question, If I would like to change  `BTD - BIND TIMESTAMP AS DATE`, where should I change it. I am new to the oracle architecture.

Comment: BTD is a connection string parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183

Comment: PL/SQL looks fine. Not sure if you can specify BTD=F in the database link, it may need to be defined in tnsnames.ora. (Although as you point out, documentation says it should default to F.)

Comment: (SQL Server) example modifying tnsnames.ora here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_database_link_oracle.htm 

An approach _without_ editing tnsnames.ora here:
http://msutic.blogspot.no/2009/07/how-to-create-database-link-without.html